How can I serialize mongodb UpdateDefinition or Filter?
I'm processing thousands of rows using BulkWriteAsync(writeModels) and it runs for a long time and then aborts with "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query".  My theory is that somehow it's something wrong a subset of documents (or perhaps the updatedefinition was misconfigured for some docs).  However, from a WriteModel object I cannot find any way to serialize it to return the filter and updatedefinition.  I have tried .toString(), .toJson(), .toBsonDocument().
How can I serialize them to some nice readable form so I can compare the failing data to the 'good data'?  When I view in VS debugger they seem to hold endless arrays that never show me anything valid.

consider logging approaches I mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78408929/9492730, as I see you need to Render your definitions

Instead of applying special logic for this use case, you could consider using logging. MongoDB C# Driver integrates with the .NET (Core) logging framework.
For details, see the documentation here.
